# unset flags that have already been set by aliases

Tags: bash, flags

Consider the following bash alias:

```
alias echo="echo -e";
```

Would there be a way to turn off the `-e` flag in further use? A syntax like `echo +e` would seem useful for me for calling just `echo` then.

Since echo is a builtin, in this particular case one could use `builtin echo` in order to archive the effect. However, I'm looking for a way to handle arbitrary bash commands as well. Moreover I'm rather looking for a way to explicitly unset a selection of flags instead of just a reset to the original command.

Comment: Why not use `unalias echo`?

Comment: The problem is that there is no general hard rule for flag syntax. So bash cannot break down the aliased command into what is a command, what is a flag, what is a file, etc. There are certain usual conventions, but bash cannot demand them, since there are other shells and e.g. `find` or `ffmpeg` or `xargs` might break.
I’ve wished for years that we’d get a formal computer-readable interface definition for each installed command, that would allow this and allow automatic generation of both man pages and network services and UIs and introspection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this specific case, `echo` has a `-E` option that disables processing of escaped characters, overriding previous uses of `-e`.

In general, there's no way to *remove* an option provided by the alias expansion, other than to avoid the alias expansion in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Added a backslash (`\`) before command will disable alias  temporarily and force to use original command.

Comment: this is already very useful. I was just thinking for a way to unset some flags and keep others. Like: alias xyz="xyz -a -b -c -d";  and then e.g. xyz +b would yield: xyz -a -c -d . But this might not be possible without a wrapping mechanism.

Comment: @AntonHarald, I think you need to write a shell function, instead of alias ,to implement this machanism.

Comment: I thought that this unflagging would be particularly useful when not just dealing with 'boolean' flags but with flags that are followed by strings. Say you configure an alias/function of a command with many parameters. But for one single case you'd just want to turn off one of them. It would certainly possible somehow to get there, it will be quite complex. I'd say the main problem is that for bash a function call like abc -fghi -x "sth" is in fact a call of the arity 3. It's up to the command to interpret the meaning of receiving 5 paramters (4 bool, 1 string).